# Are my questions not very good?

Tags: discussion

I don't tend to ask many questions as I usually find the answer here before/during feeling the need to ask one, however, I have been learning es2015(/ES6) the last few weeks using ReactJs.net, npm, webpack and a babel transpiler and have felt the need to ask questions that don't seem to attract much attention.

The last 5 I have asked have not been very fruitful and I have solved or worked around the problems myself.

What can I do to be more 'attractive' when I ask questions?

Comment: Well if you're able to figure the problems out yourself, it's a sign that you're asking the questions too early.  You should be asking the question once it's clear that you *can't* figure it out yourself.

Comment: @servy yeah fair point, i am very reluctant to actually post a question though, maybe it's indicative that i am finding this learning curve a little more difficult..